# Acyclic fibration admits a section?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration

Is that true that each acyclic fibration admits a section? If so how to see this? If not then under what condition an acyclic fibration admits a section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $p:E\to B$ is an acyclic fibration in a general model category.  There is then a commutative square $$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>{}>> E\\
@V{}VV @VV{p}V \\
B @>{1}>> B
\end{CD}$$
where $0$ is initial.  So, if the map $0\to B$ is a cofibration (i.e., if $B$ is cofibrant), there is a map $B\to E$ making the diagram commute, which is exactly a section of $p$.  That is, any acyclic fibration over a cofibrant base has a section.  In particular, if you're talking about Hurewicz fibrations that are homotopy equivalences, this works for any $B$, since every space is cofibrant in the Strøm model structure.

Alternatively, here's a more direct argument in the latter case.  Let $f:B\to E$ be a homotopy inverse of $p$ with homotopy $H:B\times I\to B$ from $pf$ to the identity.  Then since $p$ is a Hurewicz fibration, $H$ lifts a homotopy $\tilde{H}:B\times[0,1]\to E$, and then $\tilde{H}(-,1)$ will be a section of $p$.

Comment: But $p$ is just a weak homotopy equivalence, how do we know it has a homotopy inverse?

Comment: The special case I'm talking about at the end is where $p$ is a Hurewicz fibration and a homotopy equivalence (i.e., acyclic fibrations in the Strøm model structure).  In particular, it's an actual homotopy equivalence, not a weak homotopy equivalence.